# ¿Como filtrar correctamente mediante checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Tengo un filtro por checkbox, pero tiene un comportamiento extraño, cuando el checkbox de inicio lo marco no sucede nada, no muestra el filtrado, en cambio cuando lo desmarco si que muestra el filtrado, es decir, funciona al revés. No logro ver el porque de este comportamiento, muestro el código por si alguien me puede ayudar.///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [clinicListFiltered, setClinicListFiltered] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [clinicSearchConcerts, setClinicSearchConcerts] = useState<CollectionItem[]>([]);
    const [clinicSearchConcertSelected, setClinicSearchConcertSelected] = useState(-1);
    const [clinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected, setClinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected] = useState(-1);
    const [clinicSearchConcertHealtSelected, setClinicSearchConcertHealtSelected] = useState(-1);

 const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
    const [isChecked2, setIsChecked2] = useState(false);
    const [isChecked3, setIsChecked3] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {

        console.log(isChecked)
       
        setIsChecked(e.target.checked);
        handleChangeFilter()
        isChecked === true ? setClinicSearchConcertSelected(-1) :
        setClinicSearchConcertSelected(parseInt(e.target.value)) 
        

    };

    const handleChangeMutua = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log(isChecked2)
        
        setIsChecked2(e.target.checked);
        handleChangeFilter()
        isChecked2 === true ? setClinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected(-1) :
        setClinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected(parseInt(e.target.value))     

    };

    const handleChangeHealt = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log(isChecked3)
        setIsChecked3(e.target.checked);
        handleChangeFilter()
        isChecked3 === true ? setClinicSearchConcertHealtSelected(-1) :
        setClinicSearchConcertHealtSelected(parseInt(e.target.value))

    };

    const handleChangeFilter = () => {

        var resultSearch = clinicList.filter((element) => {

            var feature: number[] = [];
            if (element.featureFilterList) {
                feature = element.featureFilterList?.split(',').map(x => parseInt(x));
            }
            var isOk =
                (clinicSearchConcertSelected == -1 || feature.includes(clinicSearchConcertSelected)) &&
                (clinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected == -1 || feature.includes(clinicSearchConcertMutuaSelected)) &&
                (clinicSearchConcertHealtSelected == -1 || feature.includes(clinicSearchConcertHealtSelected))
            if (isOk) {
                return element;
            }

        });
        setClinicListFiltered(resultSearch);

    }
return (
<div className="py-3 border-b flex flex-col md:flex-row items-start md:items-center md:justify-between justify-start gap-2">
                                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                                {clinicSearchConcerts.slice(0, 1).map(fields => (
                                                    <>

                                                        <label key={fields.id} className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                                                            <input
                                                                className="sr-only peer"
                                                                type="checkbox"
                                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                                                value={fields.id}
                                                                checked={isChecked}
                                                            />
                                                            <div className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer peer-focus:ring-teal-600 
                                                                peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] 
                                                                 after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-teal-600"></div>
                                                            <span className="ml-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">{fields.name}</span>
                                                        </label>

                                                    </>

                                                ))}
                                                {clinicSearchConcerts.slice(1, 2).map(fields => (
                                                    <>

                                                        <label key={fields.id} className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                                                            <input
                                                                className="sr-only peer"
                                                                type="checkbox"
                                                                onChange={handleChangeMutua}
                                                                value={fields.id}
                                                                checked={isChecked2}
                                                            />
                                                            <div className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer peer-focus:ring-teal-600 
                                                                peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] 
                                                                 after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-teal-600"></div>
                                                            <span className="ml-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">{fields.name}</span>
                                                        </label>

                                                    </>

                                                ))}
                                                {clinicSearchConcerts.slice(2, 3).map(fields => (
                                                    <>

                                                        <label key={fields.id} className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                                                            <input
                                                                className="sr-only peer"
                                                                type="checkbox"
                                                                onChange={handleChangeHealt}
                                                                value={fields.id}
                                                                checked={isChecked3}
                                                            />
                                                            <div className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer peer-focus:ring-teal-600 
                                                                peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] 
                                                                 after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-teal-600"></div>
                                                            <span className="ml-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">{fields.name}</span>
                                                        </label>

                                                    </>

                                                ))}
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
)
}
```